# Is there a simple way to turn an Iterator[Byte] into an inputstream lazily?

Tags: scala

Given an Iterator[Byte] can I produce an InputStream without materializing the entire Iterator into memory?

Comment: Do you mean `Iterator<Byte>` ?

Comment: @ThomasFritsch yes. I'm writing Scala which uses `[ ]` for type parameters.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using Scala, there is a one line solution:

```
scala> import java.io.InputStream
                                                                                                                                                                           
scala> val itr = Iterator.range(0, 10).map(_.toByte)
val itr: Iterator[Byte] = <iterator>

scala> val ins: InputStream = () => if(itr.hasNext) itr.next & 255 else -1  // Here it is, or
//     val ins: InputStream = () => itr.nextOption.fold(-1)(_ & 255)
val ins: java.io.InputStream = anon$1@5dc218e2

scala> ins.readAllBytes()
val res0: Array[Byte] = Array(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)
```

Answer (score 2):

It is not too difficult.
Just construct an `InputStream` and implement its [`read()` method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read--)
in terms of the `Iterator`. In Java it may look like this:

```
public InputStream streamFromIterator(Iterator<Byte> iterator) {
    return new InputStream() {

        @Override
        public int read() {
            if (iterator.hasNext())
                return Byte.toUnsignedInt(iterator.next());
            else
                return -1;  // end of stream
        }
    };
}
```